# Fit Large UIView into content view

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, swift

I have inserted a UIView into my view in my storyboard and I need to take an image of this at 1000px x 1000px using the method

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(createBoard.layer.frame.size)
createBoard.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())

let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

//Save it to the camera roll
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
```

however I think swift is re-sizing the view to show in my display as when I take an image at 1000px it pixelates. my question is, can I make a  UIView at 1000px x 1000px and scale this down to show to users but when an image is taken of it, it will do so at the original 1000px?

Comment: The problem might be that you do not account for different scale factors (retina/non-retina). You could try using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_ size: CGSize, _ opaque: Bool, _ scale: CGFloat)` and pass `0` to the scale (it automatically sets the scale based on the device's screen natural scale factor)

Comment: You're welcome! Glad that helped you. Added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be that you do not account for different scale factors (retina/non-retina).

You could try using:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_ size: CGSize, _ opaque: Bool, _ scale: CGFloat)
```

and pass 0 to the scale (it automatically sets the scale based on the device's screen natural scale factor)

Finally, if you're targeting iOS7+ you could also use a newer api for view snapshots:

```
-drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:
```

[as described here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1817/_index.html)